# CSRF error when using rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain._auth_token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am calling `obtain.auth_token` from urls as follows

```
url(r'^api-token/','rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token')
```

I get back

```
{
detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

I am wondering why this happends as I was under the impression django-rest-framework was usualy CSRF exempt

Thanks

Comment: does this link help? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-rest-framework/JCf4MwNtfwM

Comment: not particularly its not really the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

That view uses a POST. DRF always requires CSRF for session-authenticated POST's.

Sensitive requests like getting an auth token should use POST for just this reason.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Check if you have sign out of the browser.

Comment: I have had to sign out, and refresh login page, then works great.
Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this too. Adding an answer in case this was unclear to anyone else.

1. Make sure you're not requesting in a context where you're already signed in, e.g. from the browser (log out, try in incognito mode, or clear your cookies if you are).
2. Make sure you're actually using the `api-token` endpoint correctly. I was initially trying to use Basic Auth, assuming this token-generating view was protected, but DRF actually expects *form data* containing `username` and `password` fields instead.

Here's a working example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
r = requests.post('http://example.com/api-token/'), data={
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
})
token = r.json()['token']
```

Comment: Just for future reference: "Note that the default obtain_auth_token view explicitly uses JSON requests and responses, rather than using default renderer and parser classes in your settings. If you need a customized version of the obtain_auth_token view, you can do so by overriding the ObtainAuthToken view class, and using that in your url conf instead." at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: @MariusSiuram Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

In order with the documentation
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/
you have to implement ajax-csrf how is explanied in
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

... if you are using angularjs you can check it [Django csrf token + Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs)