# Django csrf token + Angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I have django running on an apache server using mod_wsgi, as well as an angularjs app served directly by apache, not by django. I would like to make POST calls to the django server (running rest_framework) but I am having problems with the csrf token.

Is there someway to set the token from the server without putting `{% csrf token %}` as part of the template (since these pages aren't going through django)?

1. I would like to be able to get a csrf token through a GET request as a cookie.
2. I would like to be able to then make POST requests to the django server with the csrf token cookie value.

Comment: Your making that POST call in a Django view? Or from the same domain using another framework?

Comment: @dan-klasson the latter, same domain no framework though

Comment: Just read this guide then: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Django and AngularJS both have CSRF support already, your part is quite simple.

First, you need to enable CSRF in Django, I believe you have already done so, if not, follow Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax.

Now, Django will set a cookie named `csrftoken` on the first GET request and expects a custom HTTP header `X-CSRFToken` on later POST/PUT/DELETE requests.

For Angular, it expects the cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` and will do POST/PUT/DELETE requests with `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header, so you need to do a little bit tweak to make the two go with each other:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

Add above two lines somewhere in your js code, module.config() block is a good place for this.

That's it.

**NOTE:** This is for angular 1.1.5, older versions might need different approach.

### Update:

Since the angular app isn't served by django, in order to let the cookie to be set, angular app needs to do a GET request to django first.

Comment: He still needs to set the cookie somehow.

Comment: @dan-klasson You're right, his angular app isn't served by Django.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for the explanation on csrf and because it set me on the right path. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, and I couldn't find a reference to the `xsrfCookieNAme` and and `xsrfHeaderName` in the official docs. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Preom FYI, `xsrfCookieName` and and `xsrfHeaderName` are documented after angular 1.2.

Comment: Awesome answer: both right to the point and informative. Worked like a charm !

Comment: The bit under UPDATE got me, angular app was served as static html so I wasn't getting the token in the first place

Comment: I am getting the Set-Cookie header in login/ api which is POST. When should I call the GET request and how?

Answer (score 60):

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', ['bar']);

foo.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

And all modules services and controllers, where $http used, will send requests with csrf token.

Comment: As indicated below, this require AngularJS 1.1.5 or later.

Comment: This works. Just letting anyone reading this know... Really great post.

Answer (score 11):

After searching around, what worked for me was from [this post](http://angularjs-best-practices.blogspot.ca/2013/07/angularjs-and-xsrfcsrf-cross-site.html) with the following code:

```
angular.module( '[your module name]',
    ... [some dependencies] ...
    'ngCookies',
    ... [other dependencies] ...
)
.run( function run( $http, $cookies ){

    // For CSRF token compatibility with Django
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken');
})
```

This is of course after getting the cookie through a GET request from the django server.

I also looked into some of the other answers here, including Ye Liun's but couldn't find anything in the official docs specifying changes to the defaults options for xsrf on $httpProvider, other than [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1952) which didn't work for me at the time of me writing this post.

Comment: I'm seeing a problem with doing things this way.  When I emulate a first-time site visit in chrome with `ctrl`+`shift`+`n`, `$cookies['csrftoken'];` is `undefined` since I haven't sent any requests to my django server when that line is executed.  I do an `OPTIONS` request first and then set the `$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken']` globally since the `$cookies.csrftoken` is then valid.

Comment: I solved the undefined issue by calling `$cookiesProvider.$get()`  to generate a new local `$cookies` from `document.cookies` and then updating the csrf value on the `$http` defaults.  I did this by shamefully creating a global reference to `$cookiesProvider`: `var cookiesProvider_ref = null; app.config( function($cookiesProvider) {cookiesProvider_ref = $cookiesProvider
});`.  I then use `cookiesProvider_ref` in my login `success()` callback to  set the `$http` csrf token header field again.

Comment: I had to eventually just use the `getCookie` function recommended from Django's site as I preferred doing that to including a pointless extra trip to the server when the cookie was already sent down. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 1):

I created a Django App for my AngularJS app, in the same Django project as my (REST) API Django App, that only serves the index.html file (which is just a sym.link). In this way the CSRF Cookie is set without an additional GET request.

Please see my answer here about [AngularJS Single Page Web Application on Sub-domain A talking to a Django JSON (REST) API on Sub-domain B using CORS and CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22584318/889617)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your cookies set to disallow javascript access, you need to do the following.  In your template, before creating the django app, add this:

```
<script>
    window.csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
```

In your angular app, add this:

```
angularApp.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRFToken"] = window.csrf_token;
}]);
```

At least through Django 1.9, the CSRF token does not change with each request.  It only changes when a user logs in.  If you are doing a single page angular app, you need to make sure you reset the token on login/logout and this should work fine.

NOTE: This does not currently work in Django 1.10 or later due to the CSRF token changing on each request.  See [Pass Django CSRF token to Angular with CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40851475/2800876)