# Django + Angular: how to send angularjs $http data or params to django and interpret in django?

Tags: django, angularjs

Why can't I use params or data with $http to communicate with Django?

I have an angularjs page that gets data from a django view. In one case, I have a django view called /display that grabs a file off the server and displays it as plain text.

```
this.loadfile = function (clickedItem) {
    $http({method: 'GET' , url: '/display/'+ clickedItem.fileName})
        .success(function(data) {
                $scope.fileView.text = data;

        });
};
```

The call to /display/myfile.txt works nicely, since the filename is a simple string, as is the returned data.

Now I need to send a more complex, multiline parameter to django: a list of searchStrings and a list of filenames:

```
  this.concord = function (searchStrings, filenames) {

        $http({method: 'GET' ,
                url: '/concord/',
                data: {"searchStrings":searchStrings, "filenames":filenames}
            )
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data); // log the data coming back.
                $scope.concord = data;
            });
    };
```

According to [AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json), that should work with

```
url(r'^concord/(?P<jsondata>.*)$', views.concord, name="concord"),
```

where my view is:

```
def concord(request,jsondata) :
    jObj=simplejson.loads(jsondata)
    return HttpResponse(jObj["files"])
```

(I tried parsing request.body as well; was empty)

On the other hand, if I explicitly attach it to the url, I do get something back:

```
 $http({method: 'GET',
                url: '/concord/'+JSON.stringify({"searchStrings":searchStrings, "filenames":filenames}),

            }
            )
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.concordResults = data;
            });
```

That works!

But I must be doing this in worst way possible. Is there a way to use params or data to communicate with Django?

(PS: I have avoided django-angular package because I am already overwhelmed with learning packages: django rest, angular, bootstrap, etc... I really just want to start with bare-bones communication between angular and django. Later I will dive into more packages.)

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ < Look into that, it helps Django act more "RESTful" and makes it a lot easier for you to make data-driven views for angular to consume.

Comment: thanks -- I've started reading but obviously not far along enough to understand the post/get things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at angularjs docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you see that you can get params and post data like json in your case.

When you post, you'll do something like this:

```
$http.post('http://www.example.com/post_data_url',
           { 'key': $scope.value }
          );
```

On django side, don't add any parameter to the URL, the JSON will be inside the request, in the body to be more precise:

```
import json

def concord(request):
  dictionary = json.loads(request.body)
  # to use the value, access the created dictionary
  print dictionary['key']
  [...]
```

Comment: The main difference here is you are using POST rather than GET; I will test it further. For the moment, I'm getting  403 (FORBIDDEN) for POST (even though I'm on local host, this is probably a crsf issue). I'm running it with the JSON.stringify approach for the moment. Will see if your method works once I figure out the "Forbidden" problem.  (Thanks!)

Comment: Yes, that did it! I put in a @csrf_exempt for the moment, and got around that error. Thanks! It was simply that the GET does not have a body...(I'm guessing). Now it is a question of understanding csrf between angular and django...(more work!)

Comment: OK, just for the record: to avoid "forbidden", in my Django views: from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie, then @ensure_csrf_cookie for each (?) view that communicates with angular.

Comment: There is already a question on csrf management with angularjs/django. The answer is clear and is working. It is also more elegant than the use of @ensure_csrf_cookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs