# How send POST request in angularjs with _csrf?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-security, csrf

I want sending POST requests to service under spring security.
if i using form submission (with hidden input) - it's working fine.
But i don't know, how send request with $http.post.
my form:

```
<form method="POST" type="submit" action="http://localhost:8888/rest/post1" />
    <button>345</button>
    <input name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

it work.

I save params:

```
<script>
        var a = "${_csrf.parameterName}";
        var b = "${_csrf.token}";
</script>
```

My ng-click function:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8888/rest/post1', {"_csrf": b}, {
    "headers" :
    { "_csrf" : b }
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log("ok");

}).error(function(){

    console.log("no");
});
```

It always writing "no".

I think, that need to send variable as webForm, but how do it in $http.post?

Fiddler write: `Content-Type is 'application/json'; this inspector supports 'x-www-form-urlencoded' only`

Server console:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Help me, please!

Comment: May be this can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs][1]

Comment: no, don't help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this)

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/rest/post1",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(){return a+"="+b;},
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set "_csrf" in the request header. You are passing it as an argument for a method. This won't work. I am not much aware of angular.js but you must need to pass it as request header or request payload. I found some reference. Here it goes:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

Hope this helps you to solve your problem. Cheers !!!