# Forbidden posting from Angular to Django

Tags: angularjs, django

Hello I'm trying to do something like this

```
$http({
    url: '/',
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param('test=data'),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
```

In django

```
#urls
url(r'^$', myView),

#views
def myView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "POST", request.POST
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But I only get this: POST / 403 FORBIDDEN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django csrf token + Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@api_view(['POST'])` on the line before myView function:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def myView(request):
    //so on
```

Comment: Ok, It's works fine, but It's not what I want to. 
I need to have my html template. In template - button. When I'll click the button i need to send post from angulary to django, and in django call some method.