# CSRF token missing or incorrect. Django + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, api, csrf, django-csrf

I'm getting  CSRF token missing or incorrect error while doing a POST request to a remote django api from my localhost machine.

My settings on AngularJS:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){

$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

}]);
```

but im still getting the **CSRF token missing or incorrect** error.

I check what headers are being sent and apparently angular is not sending `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN`.

But I can see that the cookie csrftoken=something is sent.

Does anyone know what is going on?

**Request Header**

```
POST /s/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: server.somewhere.io:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 290
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/thesocialmarkt/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,pt-BR;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
Cookie: csrftoken=hiYq1bCNux1mTeQuI4eNgi97qir8pivi; sessionid=1nn1phjab5yd71yfu5k8ghdch2ho6exc
```

Comment: is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs

Comment: not since i still have the problem.

Comment: what are your django restframework settings?

Comment: we're not using the Django Rest Framework, our API is built natively within Django

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris Hawkes pointed to this stackoverflow answer given by @Ye Liu

> Since the angular app isn't served by django, in order to let the
>   cookie to be set, angular app needs to do a GET request to django
>   first.

I verified that as long as you don't make http get request, `csrftoken` cookie doesn't get set. So only

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

would not work. You first need to make if not real then mock http get request to django `rest_framework`.

**Update**: Your comments pushed me to further study it, Please read this [blog](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/) where is has mentioned as,

> CLIENT-SIDE GENERATED CSRF-TOKENS. Have the clients generate and send
>   the same unique secret value in both a Cookie and a custom HTTP
>   header. Considering a website is only allowed to read/write a Cookie
>   for its own domain, only the real site can send the same value in both
>   headers

So lets try with this single request first.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

where you are injecting `$cookies` to the controller/service.

If it works then may be writing `interceptors` would be good choice, and would help you to debug as well.

I am sure you are using AngularJs version at least 1.2, See this [changeset](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fce100a46c5681562253c3a856d67bbd35fbc2f2)
and in recent commit Angular http service checking csrf with this code,

```
var xsrfValue = urlIsSameOrigin(config.url)
            ? $$cookieReader()[config.xsrfCookieName || defaults.xsrfCookieName]
            : undefined;
        if (xsrfValue) {
          reqHeaders[(config.xsrfHeaderName || defaults.xsrfHeaderName)] = xsrfValue;
        }
```

So it's necessary that you are sending same token which is present in cookie.

Further to analyse use developer tool of your browser to see request/response with the http request and analyse headers and cookies.

Comment: Im doing a get request on page load. so i get the CSRFTOKEN with the response. as you can see on the resquest header that i posted above, the cookie csrftoken=hiYq1bCNux1mTeQuI4eNgi97qir8pivi; is setted.  whast is happening is when i try to do another request django is saying that im not sending the token. I notice that the header HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN is not sent.

Comment: Thx for you help. But i guess it wont really work as long as im on local machine. i will upload it later to the server and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using $http in AngularJS for ajax request and if you are facing any CSRF token issue then use this:

```
$http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```