# Django REST Angular $http 403 Status

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, http-post

So I have a very simple API endpoint that is supposed to determine if a user is logged in. I did decide to make it a `POST` request for the sake of hiding the response from being accessed in the browser

```
class Check(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        print request.user

        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            # a successful response for logged in

            return Response(status = HTTP_200_OK)


        # return an error status code for not logged in

        return Response(status = HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

When logged out, I get `AnonymousUser` in the console and a 401  status code as expected. However when logged in as a superuser or any other user, I get no print output and a 403 status code. This indicates that for some reason the entire callback is never entered. I've been told that it is an issue of permissions but I have `AllowAny` enabled. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]

}
```

Comment: Are you sending csrf_token in headers when you call url via angular $http ? Django forbiddens  the view if csrf cookie is being not sent

Comment: @Aniket How would I go about doing that? I thought CSRF was only necessary for Django Forms.

Comment: Yeah but you are using SessionAuthentication as per your rest settings. When using session auth you need to send csrf token.

Comment: What is the difference between basic auth and session auth?

Comment: And how do I go about using the CSRF token?

Comment: probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs) should do your job

Comment: Thank you Aniket!