# add django csrf token to angular 5 form

Tags: django, angular, angular5

im working on django-angular5 project i have a login form in angular how should i add csrf token to my form ? without what i get this error 
i searched same topic but people are using angular js that will not help me
(i ng build angular app and im using static files)

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

it is my simple form for login in home.compoenent.html

```
<form method="post">

    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="first_name" type="text" name="username" class="validate">
        <label for="first_name">نام کاربری</label>
    </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input  id="first_name" type="password" name="password" class="validate">
        <label for="first_name">کلمه عبور</label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="login"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your form you should just add `{% csrf_token %}`
you'll have something like this :

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="first_name" type="text" name="username" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">نام کاربری</label>
        </div>
       <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input  id="first_name" type="password" name="password" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">کلمه عبور</label>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="login"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: we cant use {% %} (jango template tag) there we will get this error 

`vendor.bundle.js:14136 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
</div>`

Comment: then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156452/django-csrf-token-angularjs)

Comment: that is about angular js its quite diffrent with angular 4 or 5