# Postman Django CSRF error when requesting obtain_auth_token route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, csrf

Basically the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119296/csrf-error-when-using-rest-framework-authtoken-views-obtain-auth-token) which didn't get an answer, when I try to access the token route of the rest_framework using Postman, I get a 403 that says

> "CSRF cookie not set."

I don't understand why I would need a token to request the route which is supposed to give me an authentication token, but most of all, I don't know how to get around this issue !

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the postman and delete all cookies for that request [image]

and if a problem exists go to your Django app settings.py file and disable session
as follow

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # disable this
    ),}
```

some people may suggest disabling CSRF in middleware(this is not recommended)

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ]
```

## this same in stackoverflow you can check foollowing

[Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: I have "No cookies available" in the "Manage cookies" interface, I will try to look into disable session

Comment: "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application".
I actively use the admin interface for my project, and it seems sessions are a core part of it. So I can't disable sessions, do you have any other idea ?

Comment: I don't mean session middleware i modified the answer

Comment: disabling sessions as you mentioned did not work. However, I found what was wrong : i was missing the ending "/" in my urls .py. I don't understand how it lead to that error, but making sure I had the "/" in my urls.py AND my request on Postman fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being that in my urls.py the route ended with a "/" that I forgot to add to the url in postman. I tried the opposite and the same error was thrown.